# AttributeError: module 'pyperclip' has no attribute 'paste'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep receiving this error and I'm relatively new to Python, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This code is basically copied out of the book I'm learning from, and will not run.

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RaudaR\Desktop\Work\python_work\phoneAndEmail.py", line 23, in <module>
    text = str(pyperclip.paste())
AttributeError: module 'pyperclip' has no attribute 'paste'
```

Here is the code I am Running, in Atom.

```
#! python3
# phoneAndEmail.py - Finds phone numbers and email addresses on the clipboard.
import pyperclip, re

phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?                  # area code
    (-|\s|\.)?                          # separator
    (\d{3})                             # first 3 digits
    (-|\s|\.)                           # separator
    (\d{4})                             # last 4 digits
    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?      # extension
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

# Create Email Regex.
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+                   # username
    @                                   # @ symbol
    [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+                      # domain name
    (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})                   # dot-something
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

# Find Matches in Clipboard text.
text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches = []
for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
    phoneNum = '-'.join([groups[1], groups[3], groups[5]])
    if groups[8] != '':
        phoneNum += ' x' + groups[8]
    matches.append(phoneNum)
for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0])
# Copy results to the Clipboard.
if len(matches) > 0:
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
    print('Copied to clipboard:')
    print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('No phone numbers or email addresses found.')
```

The module is in the same folder as the phoneAndEmail.py, that fixed a previous import issue i had.

Comment: if you look at the source code for `pyperclip` do you see any refereence to `paste`? Maybe it needs to be properly installed?

Comment: did you at any point have a file called `pyperclip.py` that you made? Prehaps it (or a `.pyc` version of it) is being imported by accident

Comment: Please show the code of `pyperclip.py`. Also, it is recommended that you import standard library modules (like `re`) and your own personal/third-party modules on separate lines.

Comment: I re install python and pyperclip and that solved the issue, there was an issue with pyperclip.py thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you need to check in from your working directory.

- Make sure that you don't have any file named `pyperclip.py` or `pyperclip.pyc` that might be imported instead of the actual **pyperclip library**.

If this doesn't work for you you can `pip uninstall pyperclip` and install it again `pip install pyperclip`.

Answer (score -2):

did you at any point have a file called pyperclip.py that you made? Prehaps it (or a .pyc version of it) is being imported by accident – Tadhg McDonald-Jensen Dec 16 '16 at 18:57

This worked for me.

Comment: pyperclip is an existing, publicly available module for Python.  You don't need to make the module but simply install it.